# "Remove and keep children" as keyboard shortcut in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

When editing an HTML file in Visual Studio 2013, if the cursor is put on the opening tag, for example `<div>`, it will display an editing option "Remove and keep children", which will remove the tag pair under the cursor.

I'm not sure whether this is Visual Studio's feature or Web Essential's feature, but I want to assign keyboard shortcut to it. Is that possible?